# Nested directives - cannot pass args to controller method from child directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm having some trouble with nested directives in angularjs. I want to call a controller method from a directive within another directive and am trying to pass arguments to it, however they are undefined.

I'm attempting to call remove() with three arguments from selected.html below. It was working before I introduced a parent directive (televisionFilter.js) Can anyone suggest what to do to pass these to the controller?

Thanks!

Code:

controller.js

```
$scope.remove = function(selectorToRemove, choicesArr, selectedArr){
 console.log(selectorToRemove); //undefined
 console.log(choicesArr); //undefined
 console.log(selectedArr); //undefined
};
```

televisionFilter.js

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('televisionFilter', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/television-filter.html',
    scope: {
      search: '=',
      selectedBrand: '=',
      submit: '&',
      remove: '&'
    }
  };
});
```

selected.js

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('selected', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/selected.html',
    scope:{
    choicesArr: '=',
    selectedArr: '=',
    remove: '&'
  } 
  };
});
```

list.html

```
<div television-filter search='televisionSearch' submit="submit()" selected-brand='selectedBrand' remove='remove(selectorToRemove, choicesArr, selectedArr)'></div>
```

television-filter.html

```
<div selected selected-arr='search.selectedBrands' choices-arr='search.brands' remove='remove(selectorToRemove, choicesArr, selectedArr)'>
```

selected.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="selected in selectedArr" class="filter-autocomplete-list"  ng-click="remove({selectorToRemove:selected, choicesArr:choicesArr,selectedArr:selectedArr})">
  <span class="label label-default label-text">{{selected}}</span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As soon as you add scope property to directive you create an isolated scope. So the methods you call inline with your directive markup expect those methods to be part of directive scope. Make a demo in plunker. Not clear what your arguments all are when you call functions inline

Comment: I've simplified the example to the following...http://plnkr.co/edit/B0XK9bHVA9YZIVWcmBvq?p=preview

Comment: OK.. here's a quick fix see `link` callback I added  http://plnkr.co/edit/g4n6IScxaqHwBvCnzLeV?p=preview

Comment: if you remove scope property completely from directive don't have to do anything BTW. scope will be that of it;s parent....the controller

Comment: Thanks very much. Working nicely now.

Comment: Hi.. I am having a similar problem. Is there a working plunker link? the one above is broken!!!

Comment: Satya you have to do something like - link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
    scope.YOURFUNCTION = scope.$parent.YOURFUNCTION;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers suggested in the comments by @charlietfl and @angular_james, although working, exhibit bad angular practice. Calling $parent violates the point of your isolated scope (&). To get it working, you just have to modify the of the middle directive (television-filter.html) as follows:

`<div selected selected-arr='search.selectedBrands' choices-arr='search.brands' remove='remove({selectorToRemove: selectorToRemove, choicesArr: choicesArr, selectedArr: selectedArr})'>`

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgRh92ckaWjPeeY9kptm)

Comment: How would this be done using a shared service instead? Is this an even better practice than polluting the scope ?? Please have a look at my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889929/what-is-a-good-practice-for-defining-scopes-when-some-data-is-needed-in-a-contro

Comment: Alternatively, you can reconsider whether the [scope isolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Isolating) is really necessary and possibly remove it and solve the problem altogether...